# PHP to remove data from Csv file according to matching condition

Tags: php, csv

The csv file contains

```
ID,Record
 1,R1
 2,R2
 3,R3
 4,R4
 5,R5
```

Consider the above is my csv file data and i have a variable with $ProcessAfter ='R3';  Then it should remove the first three data.
The Below is my file reading code

```
while(!feof($file)) {
   fgetcsv($file,0,$fieldseparator); //To read each line
}
```

Comment: Do you want to remove data in csv?

Comment: Consider i have 500 records , and also i have a condition Record $ProcessAfter ='R134';  R134 is a data present in 134th line so i need to remove until 134th line and process after 134th line

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$ProcessAfter = 'R3';
$flag  = 0;
$data = fopen("file_name.csv", "w+")
while (($field = fgetcsv($data,",")) !== FALSE) {
    if($field[1] == $ProcessAfter){
            $flag = 1;
    }
    if($flag == 1){
        file_put_contents("sorted_file",$field,FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
```

?>

Now use the new file for processing as it will have the sorted data